# How to Change the HyperlinkBase property in a DOCX document using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, openxml

I need to bulk set the Hyperlink Base property for a set of documents. I can open the docx using .net and OPEN XML, however I'm having a problem making the next step in getting to and changing the correct property. In the sample below I get the number of characters but am not sure that is the path I should be following.

```
Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal lst As ListBox, ByVal pattern As String, ByVal dir_info As DirectoryInfo)
    ' Get the files in this directory.
    Dim fs_infos() As FileInfo = dir_info.GetFiles(pattern)
    For Each fs_info As FileInfo In fs_infos

        Dim xmlProperties As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
        Dim wordDoc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fs_info.FullName, False)
        Dim appPart As ExtendedFilePropertiesPart = wordDoc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart
        Dim props = wordDoc.PackageProperties
        xmlProperties.Load(appPart.GetStream)
        Dim chars As XmlNodeList = xmlProperties.GetElementsByTagName("Characters")
        MessageBox.Show("Number of characters in the file = " + chars.Item(0).InnerText, "Character Count")

    Next fs_info
    fs_infos = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do what I want:

```
Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal lst As ListBox, ByVal pattern As String, ByVal dir_info As DirectoryInfo)

Dim fs_infos() As FileInfo = dir_info.GetFiles(pattern)
    Dim message As String
    For Each fs_info As FileInfo In fs_infos

        Dim wordDoc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fs_info.FullName, True)
        Dim props = wordDoc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties

        message = fs_info.Name.ToString & ": Old base hyperlink: " & props.HyperlinkBase.Text & " New base hyperlink: " & cboPaths.Text
        lstFiles.Items.Add(message)


        Dim hylnkBase As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.ExtendedProperties.HyperlinkBase = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.ExtendedProperties.HyperlinkBase()

        hylnkBase.Text = cboPaths.Text

        props.HyperlinkBase = hylnkBase

        wordDoc.Close()

    Next fs_info
    fs_infos = Nothing End Sub
```